# Media Queries Not Working with Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I am currently working on a Wordpress website and attempting to code the responsive looks for handheld devices and tablets but the media queries are not working.

Currently only trying portrait on iPhone and it will not take.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
`/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */ @media only screen and (max-width : 400px) { h1#logo {margin-top:-6%; margin-left:10px;} .topnav.navRight {left:15%; margin-top: -1%;} #header .social-icons {margin-top:-3%; position:absolute; margin-left:17% !important;} #main_menu {margin-top:-10% !important;} }`
```

The website can be located at luludew.com/wp

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you include this meta tag in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```